# Histogram - Wine Data Set - R

Tags: r, histogram

**I have solved my problem. I was making a small error that I did not see as I am still new to R. Thank you for the help!**

I am having a lot of trouble trying to make a histogram from the wine data set available from UCI Machine Learning Repository. It is for a homework assignment so I don't want/can't have the exact answer, but rather be pointed in the right direction. I have been running around in circles for days.

```
#CSV <- comma separated values
  wine <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\ASHLEY~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpGqbfyN\\data167c33fa34b4", header=FALSE)
  wine <- gsub(",", "", wine)   # remove comma
  hist(wine)
```

Comment: Why are you removing commas??? `read.csv` does that for you... Also you probably want to look at some particular variable in the wine dataset (so for instance you should do `hist(wine$variablename)`). Try looking at the output of `head(wine)` or `str(wine)`.

Comment: Also, what error message are you are getting?

Comment: I get either 'x must be numerical' or 'invalid number of breaks'. I receive the 'x must be numerical' error when doing hist(wine). I have tried everything I can think of, but no solutions I've researched work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try reading the data directly from the repo instead of saving it to a file first...

```
library("httr")
a <- GET("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data")
df <- read.csv(textConnection(content(a)), header=F)
```

Histograms seems to work fine from here...